# Can $g$ necessarily be extended to be an entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $g: \overline{\mathbb{D}} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$. Assume in addition that $g(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $|z| = 1$.

**Question.** Can $g$ necessarily be extended to be an entire function?

Comment: yes, choose  a Mobius transformation $m$ mapping the real line to the unit circle and apply Schwarz's reflection principle to $g\circ m$

Comment: To add on Schwarz's reflection principle : if $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $|z|< 1$ then $\overline{g(1/\overline{z})}$ is holomorphic on $|z| > 1$. If $g(z)$ is continuous on $|z|\le 1$ and real on $|z| = 1$ then $f(z) = g(z) 1_{|z|\le 1} + \overline{g(1/\overline{z})} 1_{|z| > 1}$ is holomorphic on $|z| \ne 1$ and continuous on $\mathbb{C}$ which means it is entire, by Morera's theorem